# how to export display column name in sharepoint online export to excel instead of internal column name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, powerapps-forms, share

how to SharePoint online export to excel shows internal name instead of display name?
how to export display column  name in sharepoint online export to excel instead of internal column name

Answer (score 0):

Please use following PowerShell.

```
#Config Parameter
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
$ListName = "list"
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\ListData.csv"
$ListDataCollection= @()
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$Counter = 0
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 2000
 
#Get all items from list
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
        $ListItem  = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property FieldValuesAsText
        $ListRow = New-Object PSObject
        $Counter++
        Get-PnPField -List $ListName | ForEach-Object {
            $ListRow | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name $_.InternalName -Value $ListItem[$_.InternalName]
            }
        Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($Counter / $($ListItems.Count)  * 100) -Activity "Exporting List Items..." -Status  "Exporting Item $Counter of $($ListItems.Count)"
        $ListDataCollection += $ListRow
}
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListDataCollection | Export-CSV $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```